# Invariant subspaces of symmetric operators

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, invariant-subspace

I haven't found anywhere that discusses representations of the symmetric group in a way that applies to this situation, and I'd appreciate any pointers/resources/phrases-to-Google.

Consider a vector space $V$, and form the $N$-fold tensor product $\otimes^NV$. The symmetric group $S_N$ has a natural action on $\otimes^N V$ given by $\sigma\cdot( v_1\otimes\cdots\otimes v_N)=v_{\sigma(1)}\otimes\cdots\otimes v_{\sigma(N)}$. I want to consider the set of all linear operators $L$ on $\otimes^N V$ satisfying $\sigma L=L\sigma$. I'll call this set $\mathcal G$. It clearly forms a semigroup (and if it makes things easier, I'm happy to restrict $L$ to be invertible, or unitary, so that $\mathcal G$ forms a group).

The action of $\mathcal G$ on $\otimes ^N V$ is not irreducible. Two obvious invariant subspaces are the symmetric subspace, which has dimension $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}N+\text{dim}(V)-1\\N\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, and the antisymmetric subspace, which has dimension $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}\text{dim}(V)\\N\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. Each of these is irreducible.

My question is **How many irreducible subspaces are there?** For $N>2$, there clearly is at least one more irreducible subspace, since the dimensions of the symmetric and antisymmetric subspaces don't add up to $\text{dim}(V)^N$. But is this third subspace irreducible, or does it decompose into some number of irreducible subspaces?

---

You can read more context for this question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/560991/invariant-subspaces-of-multi-particle-hamiltonians), where it's phrased in the language of multi-particle quantum mechanics.

Comment: The phrase you want to google is "Schur-Weyl duality".

Comment: @Nate this seems to be VERY CLOSE to what I want! But as far as I can tell, Schur-Weyl duality restricts you to linear maps of the form $g\otimes\cdots\otimes g$, whereas I am interested in more general elements of $GL(\otimes^N V)$. Unless I'm overlooking something?

Comment: Okay the next phrase you want to look up, still in the context of Schur-Weyl duality, is the "double centralizer property" or "double commutant theorem".  It tells us that the algebra of maps commuting with the action of $S_n$ is equal to the span of the maps coming from $GL(V)$.

Comment: @Nate ok, that is exactly what I needed! For some reason that seemed very counter-intuitive to me until I explicitly worked out some examples. Thank you for your help!